# Skobbler Android Cannot Animate custom SKAnnotationView

Tags: android, animation, skmaps

How can I animate an SKAnnotationView that has a Custom View. I've inflated it properly and it shows up correctly like :

```
    SKAnnotation annotationFromView = new SKAnnotation(11);
    annotationFromView.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.423573, 37.761349));
    annotationFromView.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
    customView =
            (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_custom_view, null, false);
    //  If width and height of the view  are not power of 2 the actual size of the image will be the next power of 2 of max(width,height).
    annotationView.setView(customView);
    annotationFromView.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotationFromView, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
```

On click, I'd like to make it invisible. I get the appropriate RelativeLayout and it's the correct instance however, it won't mutate the animation state. Why is the instance correct and not null but the animation alpha change not carried out?

```
    @Override
    public void onAnnotationSelected(final SKAnnotation annotation) {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)annotation.getAnnotationView().getView();
                layout.setAlpha(0);
                break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using `SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE` on `mapView.addAnnotation` method which will disable drop animations.
2. `SKAnnotationView` are not live views.  You cannot edit or change them without updating annotation view.